# Did Voldemort ever learn that Snape was Dumbledore's guy?

Tags: harry-potter

After Snape killed Dumbledore, Snape became one of closest to Voldemort. In the end, Voldemort killed Snape only because he wanted the allegiance of *Elder Wand* (and, he was mistaken about the rules). Did Voldemort ever learn that Snape was Dumbledore's guy?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well, Harry told him in their final confrontation:

> “Severus Snape wasn’t yours,” said Harry. “**Snape was Dumbledore’s, Dumbledore’s from the moment you started hunting down my mother.** And you never realized it, because of the thing you can’t understand. You never saw Snape cast a Patronus, did you, Riddle?”
>
> — *Deathly Hallows*, chapter 36 (*The Flaw in the Plan*)

and goes on to explain Snape’s love for Lily, which of course gets dismissed.

It’s not clear whether Voldemort believed or accepted what Harry said. He makes a comment about how Snape’s allegiance is irrelevant (because now Snape is dead), but he’s dead before he can say anything more useful.

Comment: Did Voldemort believe providing Snape killed Dumbledore?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 Sorry, I don’t quite understand. What did or didn’t Voldemort believe?

Comment: Harry told about Snape's allegiance for pre-Dumbledore era. Why would Voldemort believe Harry's words (for post-Dumbledore era) providing Snape killed Dumbledore and told DEs the date of Harry's departure?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 how many snapes would a snape snaper snape if a snape snaper could snape snapes?  (seriously, I've still no Idea what are you trying to ask)

Comment: @Lohoris Harry referenced her mom's death, that's reasonable. But, after this event, Snape killed Dumbledore which shows that Lily's death didn't affect Snape or the emotions faded away. Why would Voldemort believe Harry?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 I think you meant "Did Voldemort believe [what Harry said] *given that* Snape killed Dumbledore?" (or perhaps "provided that" - in any case "providing" is probably confusing people)

Comment: @Jefromi That's when it would be said that Voldemort really learned the fact.

Comment: @Lohoris Yea, for Grammar! So how many snapes would a snape snape snape?

Answer (score 19):

No. Snape had fully fooled Voldemort. Being the egomaniac that he was, he would have mentioned that he knew the truth as he killed Snape, instead he only mentioned that he was killing him to gain mastery of the Elder Wand.

The irony being that Snape told Bellatrix exactly what he had done. “You think he is mistaken? Or that I have somehow hoodwinked him? Fooled…the most accomplished Legilimens the world has ever seen?”(Half Blood Prince pg 26).

The clue comes from Snape's lessons with Harry in Occlumency, or hiding your thoughts. Basically, Snape learned how to hide his true motives from Voldemort even though he was a great mind-reader. Convincing him that he had wormed his way into Dumbledore's trust even though Snape was truly waiting for the right moment to undo Voldemort.

Comment: Forgot about the revelation Harry gave him...I need to read the books again. But the point is that Snape took his secret to the grave.

Comment: Technically he didn't seeing as how he gave all the relevant memories to Harry (including the ones Harry already saw when he rudely invaded Severus's memories in OotP - just because Severus had left the room doesn't mean he had the right to do that - which shows just how much he wanted to reveal his secrets to). And Harry made sure it was known; Rowling even suggests he would have made sure Severus had a portrait in the headmaster's office.

Answer (score 0):

Snape probably just had to keep his genuine dislike for Harry up front in his mind, and Voldemort would never have bothered to dig any deeper.